# How can I generate time-zones from latitude and longitude .tif raster objects?

Tags: r, gis, r-raster

I would really appreciate any help on this.

I need to reclassify the total values of water consumption by water density and time zones.

I have done it by water density, but I am stuck in how to do it by time zones.

Data can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11ZWF3pycmpAsLzTyens8VoP6x8l43T4R):

Here my example code:

```
lowbound<- seq(0,cellStats(denty,"max", na.rm=TRUE),1000) #bands by 1k
upbound<-lowbound+1000
band<-upbound/1000
rclmat <- as.matrix(cbind(lowbound,upbound,band))
rclmat<-rclmat[1:length(rclmat[,1]),]
#here I need to reclassify by rclmat and time zone
#I would like some insights on how to get here time zone from lat/long to be used on reclassify function
water_density<- reclassify(denty, rclmat, include.lowest=TRUE, right=FALSE)

#stats per band
sumt<-zonal(total,water_density,"sum")
stats2<-cbind(sumt[,2])
```

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't provide a link to data. When (not if) that link goes dry, this question will be unreproducible, rendering it much less useful. Please insert sufficient/sample data, suggestions for doing so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/3358272

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a time zone from a location using latitude and longitude coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates)